# Не работает AjaxForm modx

Tags: html, ajax, form, modx

При отправке письма через AjaxForm с FormIt не приходят письма, хотя сообщение удачной отправки есть, в базу письмо не сохранятся.

```html
[[!AjaxForm? 
&form=`contact_form` 
&snippet=`FormIt` 
&hooks=`FormitSaveForm,email`
&emailSubject=`Сообщение с нашего сайта`
&emailTo=`veterangrupp@mail.ru`
&emailFrom=`veterangrupp@mail.ru`
&emailTpl=`tpl.email`
&validate=`name:minLength=^2^,email:email:required,message:minLength=^10^,g-recaptcha-response:required`
&validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
&successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
]]


<form action="" method="post" class="ajax_form af_example">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="af_name">[[%af_label_name]]</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="af_name" name="name" value="[[+fi.name]]" placeholder="" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="error_name">[[+fi.error.name]]</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="af_email">[[%af_label_email]]</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" id="af_email" name="email" value="[[+fi.email]]" placeholder="" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="error_email">[[+fi.error.email]]</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="af_message">[[%af_label_message]]</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="af_message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5">[[+fi.message]]</textarea>
            <span class="error_message">[[+fi.error.message]]</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">[[%af_reset]]</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">[[%af_submit]]</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    [[+fi.success:is=`1`:then=`
    <div class="alert alert-success">[[+fi.successMessage]]</div>
    `]]
    [[+fi.validation_error:is=`1`:then=`
    <div class="alert alert-danger">[[+fi.validation_error_message]]</div>
    `]]
</form>

<h3>Сообщение</h3>
<p>С Сайта: [[++site_name]]</p>
<p>От кого: [[+name]]</p>
<p>E-mail: [[+email]]</p>
<p>Сообщение: [[+message]]</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами хуки вот так `` &hooks=`email,FormitSaveForm ``
В Formit `hooks` выполняется последовательно.

Так же в параметре `&validate` уберите `g-recaptcha-response:required`, если вы не используете Google Recaptcha. Если вам нужна capta то нужно подключить соответствующий хук и настроить его.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, попробуйте просто Formit(AjaxForm есть обертка для него) запустить с учетом корректировок от Fapalz. 
Если не поможет, подиагностируйте отправку и доставку писем при помощи компонента QuickEmail